# How to orderBy() after take() in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to use `orderBy` after picking the latest 5 records with Laravel Eloquent:

```
Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->orderBy('name', 'asc')->get();
```

However with that query the second `orderBy` (name) is not executed and I just get five records ordered by `created_at`.

Expected result should be the 5 latest records ordered by their names.

Not the 5 ordered and latest records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a collection of 5 latest records:

```
$books = Book::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(5)->get();
```

Sort the collection:

```
$books = $books->sortBy('name');
```